# MDX query to get employees under given supervisor with parent child relationship

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

I have employee dimension in my cube where each employee has a supervisor which is also an employee. The sample data set is,

```
Employee ID | Supervisor ID | Name
     1             0          ABC
     2             1          AAA
     3             1          BBB
     4             2          CCC
     5             2          DDD
     6             4          EEE
     7             3          FFF
```

I want to get the all employees under given supervisor. E.g. If the supervisor is 2, then the result should be

```
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

using below query i can get all the employees

SELECT {AddCalculatedMembers({[Employee].[EmployeeName].Children})} ON COLUMNS FROM [MY_CUBE]

I am new to MDX and please tell me how to write MDX query for above requirement.

---

@mmarie
I already have a cube. But not sure whether I implemented it correctly. My schema is as below,

1. The dimension "dimEmployee" has columns "EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Dept".
2. Also I have used bridge table "BridgeEmployee" and it has columns "ParentEmployeeID, ChildEmployeeID, Distance"

sample data in bridge are,

```
ParentEmployeeID | ChildEmployeeID | Distance
     1                    1              0
     2                    2              0
     1                    2              1
     3                    3              0
     1                    3              1
     4                    4              0
     2                    4              1
     1                    4              2
```

I am using SSAS and I have implemented the bridge table as Measure Group.

Comment: Do you have this parent-child relationship already set up in a hierarchy in your cube and you just want to query it? Or are you trying to create it?

Comment: I have replied you as an answer as it is a lengthy answer :)

Comment: I typically see this implimented as a Parent-child dimension. For instance, the ParentEmployeeID might be part of the Employee dimension.  Then you create a parent-child hierarchy in that dimension.  It can then be related to any facts that relate to the employee dimension. Here are some links that might be helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846.aspx  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167115.aspx